# Table sorting in twitter bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover gradienttable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Sub State</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Severity</th>                   
                <th>InstanceNum</th>
                <th>CreatedBy</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var incident in Model.GetActiveIncidents())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><a target="_blank" href=@incident.Url>@incident.Id</a></td>
                    <td>@incident.State</td>
                    <td>@incident.SubState</td>
                    <td>@incident.Title</td>
                    <td>@incident.Severity</td>
                    <td>@incident.InstanceNum</td>
                    <td>@incident.CreatedBy</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>   
</div>
```

The code above is the way i populate data into my table

How can i make this table sort enabled for twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 version. I referred one of the question on stackoverflow and tried using it by it didnt work [How can I make table being capable of sorting with twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650735/how-can-i-make-table-being-capable-of-sorting-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: not hard to find tablesorting plugins...let google be your friend

Comment: There are several plugins to go with. For example: - http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Data-Grid-Table-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap/ - http://www.pontikis.net/labs/bs_grid/demo/ - https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html <-my favorite choice Please tell me if I understood your question correctly.