# Sort table rows In Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please show me an example of code that I would have to use to sort a column of a table in Bootstrap?

For example, if I want to sort by price, or by name.

Comment: I don't think its possible in pure `html` + `bootstrap`, you might need a plugin or custom `js`. Was there any effort to [**look**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767748/table-sorting-in-twitter-bootstrap-3-1-1) for a solution?

Comment: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html . This link has an example of a sorting table with code.  However, it is not compatible with the new bootstrap version.  I was hoping someone had newer example code that they could share.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

#### These examples are *minified* because StackOverflow has a maximum character limit and links to external code are discouraged since links can break.

#### There are multiple plugins if you look: [Bootstrap Sortable](https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable), [Bootstrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) or [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap#Example).

**Bootstrap 3 with DataTables Example:**
[Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) & [DataTables Docs](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><div class=container><h1>Bootstrap 3 DataTables</h1><table cellspacing=0 class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped"id=example width=100%><thead><tr><th>Name<th>Position<th>Office<th>Salary<tbody><tr><td>Tiger Nixon<td>System Architect<td>Edinburgh<td>$320,800<tr><td>Garrett Winters<td>Accountant<td>Tokyo<td>$170,750<tr><td>Ashton Cox<td>Junior Technical Author<td>San Francisco<td>$86,000<tr><td>Cedric Kelly<td>Senior Javascript Developer<td>Edinburgh<td>$433,060<tr><td>Airi Satou<td>Accountant<td>Tokyo<td>$162,700<tr><td>Brielle Williamson<td>Integration Specialist<td>New York<td>$372,000<tr><td>Herrod Chandler<td>Sales Assistant<td>San Francisco<td>$137,500<tr><td>Rhona Davidson<td>Integration Specialist<td>Tokyo<td>$327,900<tr><td>Colleen Hurst<td>Javascript Developer<td>San Francisco<td>$205,500<tr><td>Sonya Frost<td>Software Engineer<td>Edinburgh<td>$103,600<tr><td>Jena Gaines<td>Office Manager<td>London<td>$90,560<tr><td>Quinn Flynn<td>Support Lead<td>Edinburgh<td>$342,000<tr><td>Charde Marshall<td>Regional Director<td>San Francisco<td>$470,600<tr><td>Haley Kennedy<td>Senior Marketing Designer<td>London<td>$313,500<tr><td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick<td>Regional Director<td>London<td>$385,750<tr><td>Michael Silva<td>Marketing Designer<td>London<td>$198,500<tr><td>Paul Byrd<td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)<td>New York<td>$725,000<tr><td>Gloria Little<td>Systems Administrator<td>New York<td>$237,500<tr><td>Bradley Greer<td>Software Engineer<td>London<td>$132,000<tr><td>Dai Rios<td>Personnel Lead<td>Edinburgh<td>$217,500<tr><td>Jenette Caldwell<td>Development Lead<td>New York<td>$345,000<tr><td>Yuri Berry<td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)<td>New York<td>$675,000<tr><td>Caesar Vance<td>Pre-Sales Support<td>New York<td>$106,450<tr><td>Doris Wilder<td>Sales Assistant<td>Sidney<td>$85,600<tr><td>Angelica Ramos<td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)<td>London<td>$1,200,000<tr><td>Gavin Joyce<td>Developer<td>Edinburgh<td>$92,575<tr><td>Jennifer Chang<td>Regional Director<td>Singapore<td>$357,650<tr><td>Brenden Wagner<td>Software Engineer<td>San Francisco<td>$206,850<tr><td>Fiona Green<td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)<td>San Francisco<td>$850,000<tr><td>Shou Itou<td>Regional Marketing<td>Tokyo<td>$163,000<tr><td>Michelle House<td>Integration Specialist<td>Sidney<td>$95,400<tr><td>Suki Burks<td>Developer<td>London<td>$114,500<tr><td>Prescott Bartlett<td>Technical Author<td>London<td>$145,000<tr><td>Gavin Cortez<td>Team Leader<td>San Francisco<td>$235,500<tr><td>Martena Mccray<td>Post-Sales support<td>Edinburgh<td>$324,050<tr><td>Unity Butler<td>Marketing Designer<td>San Francisco<td>$85,675<tr><td>Howard Hatfield<td>Office Manager<td>San Francisco<td>$164,500<tr><td>Hope Fuentes<td>Secretary<td>San Francisco<td>$109,850<tr><td>Vivian Harrell<td>Financial Controller<td>San Francisco<td>$452,500<tr><td>Timothy Mooney<td>Office Manager<td>London<td>$136,200<tr><td>Jackson Bradshaw<td>Director<td>New York<td>$645,750<tr><td>Olivia Liang<td>Support Engineer<td>Singapore<td>$234,500<tr><td>Bruno Nash<td>Software Engineer<td>London<td>$163,500<tr><td>Sakura Yamamoto<td>Support Engineer<td>Tokyo<td>$139,575<tr><td>Thor Walton<td>Developer<td>New York<td>$98,540<tr><td>Finn Camacho<td>Support Engineer<td>San Francisco<td>$87,500<tr><td>Serge Baldwin<td>Data Coordinator<td>Singapore<td>$138,575<tr><td>Zenaida Frank<td>Software Engineer<td>New York<td>$125,250<tr><td>Zorita Serrano<td>Software Engineer<td>San Francisco<td>$115,000<tr><td>Jennifer Acosta<td>Junior Javascript Developer<td>Edinburgh<td>$75,650<tr><td>Cara Stevens<td>Sales Assistant<td>New York<td>$145,600<tr><td>Hermione Butler<td>Regional Director<td>London<td>$356,250<tr><td>Lael Greer<td>Systems Administrator<td>London<td>$103,500<tr><td>Jonas Alexander<td>Developer<td>San Francisco<td>$86,500<tr><td>Shad Decker<td>Regional Director<td>Edinburgh<td>$183,000<tr><td>Michael Bruce<td>Javascript Developer<td>Singapore<td>$183,000<tr><td>Donna Snider<td>Customer Support<td>New York<td>$112,000</table></div><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js></script><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js></script>
```

**Bootstrap 4 with DataTables Example:**
[Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/) & [DataTables Docs](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css rel=stylesheet><div class=container><h1>Bootstrap 4 DataTables</h1><table cellspacing=0 class="table table-bordered table-hover table-inverse table-striped"id=example width=100%><thead><tr><th>Name<th>Position<th>Office<th>Age<th>Start date<th>Salary<tfoot><tr><th>Name<th>Position<th>Office<th>Age<th>Start date<th>Salary<tbody><tr><td>Tiger Nixon<td>System Architect<td>Edinburgh<td>61<td>2011/04/25<td>$320,800<tr><td>Garrett Winters<td>Accountant<td>Tokyo<td>63<td>2011/07/25<td>$170,750<tr><td>Ashton Cox<td>Junior Technical Author<td>San Francisco<td>66<td>2009/01/12<td>$86,000<tr><td>Cedric Kelly<td>Senior Javascript Developer<td>Edinburgh<td>22<td>2012/03/29<td>$433,060<tr><td>Airi Satou<td>Accountant<td>Tokyo<td>33<td>2008/11/28<td>$162,700<tr><td>Brielle Williamson<td>Integration Specialist<td>New York<td>61<td>2012/12/02<td>$372,000<tr><td>Herrod Chandler<td>Sales Assistant<td>San Francisco<td>59<td>2012/08/06<td>$137,500<tr><td>Rhona Davidson<td>Integration Specialist<td>Tokyo<td>55<td>2010/10/14<td>$327,900<tr><td>Colleen Hurst<td>Javascript Developer<td>San Francisco<td>39<td>2009/09/15<td>$205,500<tr><td>Sonya Frost<td>Software Engineer<td>Edinburgh<td>23<td>2008/12/13<td>$103,600<tr><td>Jena Gaines<td>Office Manager<td>London<td>30<td>2008/12/19<td>$90,560<tr><td>Quinn Flynn<td>Support Lead<td>Edinburgh<td>22<td>2013/03/03<td>$342,000<tr><td>Charde Marshall<td>Regional Director<td>San Francisco<td>36<td>2008/10/16<td>$470,600<tr><td>Haley Kennedy<td>Senior Marketing Designer<td>London<td>43<td>2012/12/18<td>$313,500<tr><td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick<td>Regional Director<td>London<td>19<td>2010/03/17<td>$385,750<tr><td>Michael Silva<td>Marketing Designer<td>London<td>66<td>2012/11/27<td>$198,500<tr><td>Paul Byrd<td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)<td>New York<td>64<td>2010/06/09<td>$725,000<tr><td>Gloria Little<td>Systems Administrator<td>New York<td>59<td>2009/04/10<td>$237,500<tr><td>Bradley Greer<td>Software Engineer<td>London<td>41<td>2012/10/13<td>$132,000<tr><td>Dai Rios<td>Personnel Lead<td>Edinburgh<td>35<td>2012/09/26<td>$217,500<tr><td>Jenette Caldwell<td>Development Lead<td>New York<td>30<td>2011/09/03<td>$345,000<tr><td>Yuri Berry<td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)<td>New York<td>40<td>2009/06/25<td>$675,000<tr><td>Caesar Vance<td>Pre-Sales Support<td>New York<td>21<td>2011/12/12<td>$106,450<tr><td>Doris Wilder<td>Sales Assistant<td>Sidney<td>23<td>2010/09/20<td>$85,600<tr><td>Angelica Ramos<td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)<td>London<td>47<td>2009/10/09<td>$1,200,000<tr><td>Gavin Joyce<td>Developer<td>Edinburgh<td>42<td>2010/12/22<td>$92,575<tr><td>Jennifer Chang<td>Regional Director<td>Singapore<td>28<td>2010/11/14<td>$357,650<tr><td>Brenden Wagner<td>Software Engineer<td>San Francisco<td>28<td>2011/06/07<td>$206,850<tr><td>Fiona Green<td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)<td>San Francisco<td>48<td>2010/03/11<td>$850,000<tr><td>Shou Itou<td>Regional Marketing<td>Tokyo<td>20<td>2011/08/14<td>$163,000<tr><td>Michelle House<td>Integration Specialist<td>Sidney<td>37<td>2011/06/02<td>$95,400<tr><td>Suki Burks<td>Developer<td>London<td>53<td>2009/10/22<td>$114,500<tr><td>Prescott Bartlett<td>Technical Author<td>London<td>27<td>2011/05/07<td>$145,000<tr><td>Gavin Cortez<td>Team Leader<td>San Francisco<td>22<td>2008/10/26<td>$235,500<tr><td>Martena Mccray<td>Post-Sales support<td>Edinburgh<td>46<td>2011/03/09<td>$324,050<tr><td>Unity Butler<td>Marketing Designer<td>San Francisco<td>47<td>2009/12/09<td>$85,675<tr><td>Howard Hatfield<td>Office Manager<td>San Francisco<td>51<td>2008/12/16<td>$164,500<tr><td>Hope Fuentes<td>Secretary<td>San Francisco<td>41<td>2010/02/12<td>$109,850<tr><td>Vivian Harrell<td>Financial Controller<td>San Francisco<td>62<td>2009/02/14<td>$452,500<tr><td>Timothy Mooney<td>Office Manager<td>London<td>37<td>2008/12/11<td>$136,200<tr><td>Jackson Bradshaw<td>Director<td>New York<td>65<td>2008/09/26<td>$645,750<tr><td>Olivia Liang<td>Support Engineer<td>Singapore<td>64<td>2011/02/03<td>$234,500<tr><td>Bruno Nash<td>Software Engineer<td>London<td>38<td>2011/05/03<td>$163,500<tr><td>Sakura Yamamoto<td>Support Engineer<td>Tokyo<td>37<td>2009/08/19<td>$139,575<tr><td>Thor Walton<td>Developer<td>New York<td>61<td>2013/08/11<td>$98,540<tr><td>Finn Camacho<td>Support Engineer<td>San Francisco<td>47<td>2009/07/07<td>$87,500<tr><td>Serge Baldwin<td>Data Coordinator<td>Singapore<td>64<td>2012/04/09<td>$138,575<tr><td>Zenaida Frank<td>Software Engineer<td>New York<td>63<td>2010/01/04<td>$125,250<tr><td>Zorita Serrano<td>Software Engineer<td>San Francisco<td>56<td>2012/06/01<td>$115,000<tr><td>Jennifer Acosta<td>Junior Javascript Developer<td>Edinburgh<td>43<td>2013/02/01<td>$75,650<tr><td>Cara Stevens<td>Sales Assistant<td>New York<td>46<td>2011/12/06<td>$145,600<tr><td>Hermione Butler<td>Regional Director<td>London<td>47<td>2011/03/21<td>$356,250<tr><td>Lael Greer<td>Systems Administrator<td>London<td>21<td>2009/02/27<td>$103,500<tr><td>Jonas Alexander<td>Developer<td>San Francisco<td>30<td>2010/07/14<td>$86,500<tr><td>Shad Decker<td>Regional Director<td>Edinburgh<td>51<td>2008/11/13<td>$183,000<tr><td>Michael Bruce<td>Javascript Developer<td>Singapore<td>29<td>2011/06/27<td>$183,000<tr><td>Donna Snider<td>Customer Support<td>New York<td>27<td>2011/01/25<td>$112,000</table></div><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js></script><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js></script>
```

**Bootstrap 3 with Bootstrap Table Example:** [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/) & [Bootstrap Table Docs](https://bootstrap-table.com/)

```html
<link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/bootstrap-table.min.css rel=stylesheet><table data-sort-name=stargazers_count data-sort-order=desc data-toggle=table data-url="https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos?type=owner&sort=full_name&direction=asc&per_page=100&page=1"><thead><tr><th data-field=name data-sortable=true>Name<th data-field=stargazers_count data-sortable=true>Stars<th data-field=forks_count data-sortable=true>Forks<th data-field=description data-sortable=true>Description</thead></table><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js></script><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/bootstrap-table.min.js></script>
```

**Bootstrap 3 with Bootstrap Sortable Example:** [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/) & [Bootstrap Sortable Docs](https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable)

```js
function randomDate(t,e){return new Date(t.getTime()+Math.random()*(e.getTime()-t.getTime()))}function randomName(){return["Jack","Peter","Frank","Steven"][Math.floor(4*Math.random())]+" "+["White","Jackson","Sinatra","Spielberg"][Math.floor(4*Math.random())]}function newTableRow(){var t=moment(randomDate(new Date(2e3,0,1),new Date)).format("D.M.YYYY"),e=Math.round(Math.random()*Math.random()*100*100)/100,a=Math.round(Math.random()*Math.random()*100*100)/100,r=Math.round(Math.random()*Math.random()*100*100)/100;return"<tr><td>"+randomName()+"</td><td>"+e+"</td><td>"+a+"</td><td>"+r+"</td><td>"+Math.round(100*(e+a+r))/100+"</td><td data-dateformat='D-M-YYYY'>"+t+"</td></tr>"}function customSort(){alert("Custom sort.")}!function(t,e){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("tinysort",function(){return e}):t.tinysort=e}(this,function(){"use strict";function t(t,e){for(var a,r=t.length,o=r;o--;)e(t[a=r-o-1],a)}function e(t,e,a){for(var o in e)(a||t[o]===r)&&(t[o]=e[o]);return t}function a(t,e,a){u.push({prepare:t,sort:e,sortBy:a})}var r,o=!1,n=null,s=window,d=s.document,i=parseFloat,l=/(-?\d+\.?\d*)\s*$/g,c=/(\d+\.?\d*)\s*$/g,u=[],f=0,h=0,p=String.fromCharCode(4095),m={selector:n,order:"asc",attr:n,data:n,useVal:o,place:"org",returns:o,cases:o,natural:o,forceStrings:o,ignoreDashes:o,sortFunction:n,useFlex:o,emptyEnd:o};return s.Element&&function(t){t.matchesSelector=t.matchesSelector||t.mozMatchesSelector||t.msMatchesSelector||t.oMatchesSelector||t.webkitMatchesSelector||function(t){for(var e=this,a=(e.parentNode||e.document).querySelectorAll(t),r=-1;a[++r]&&a[r]!=e;);return!!a[r]}}(Element.prototype),e(a,{loop:t}),e(function(a,s){function v(t){var a=!!t.selector,r=a&&":"===t.selector[0],o=e(t||{},m);E.push(e({hasSelector:a,hasAttr:!(o.attr===n||""===o.attr),hasData:o.data!==n,hasFilter:r,sortReturnNumber:"asc"===o.order?1:-1},o))}function b(t,e,a){for(var r=a(t.toString()),o=a(e.toString()),n=0;r[n]&&o[n];n++)if(r[n]!==o[n]){var s=Number(r[n]),d=Number(o[n]);return s==r[n]&&d==o[n]?s-d:r[n]>o[n]?1:-1}return r.length-o.length}function g(t){for(var e,a,r=[],o=0,n=-1,s=0;e=(a=t.charAt(o++)).charCodeAt(0);){var d=46==e||e>=48&&57>=e;d!==s&&(r[++n]="",s=d),r[n]+=a}return r}function w(){return Y.forEach(function(t){F.appendChild(t.elm)}),F}function S(t){var e=t.elm,a=d.createElement("div");return t.ghost=a,e.parentNode.insertBefore(a,e),t}function y(t,e){var a=t.ghost,r=a.parentNode;r.insertBefore(e,a),r.removeChild(a),delete t.ghost}function C(t,e){var a,r=t.elm;return e.selector&&(e.hasFilter?r.matchesSelector(e.selector)||(r=n):r=r.querySelector(e.selector)),e.hasAttr?a=r.getAttribute(e.attr):e.useVal?a=r.value||r.getAttribute("value"):e.hasData?a=r.getAttribute("data-"+e.data):r&&(a=r.textContent),M(a)&&(e.cases||(a=a.toLowerCase()),a=a.replace(/\s+/g," ")),null===a&&(a=p),a}function M(t){return"string"==typeof t}M(a)&&(a=d.querySelectorAll(a)),0===a.length&&console.warn("No elements to sort");var x,N,F=d.createDocumentFragment(),D=[],Y=[],$=[],E=[],k=!0,A=a.length&&a[0].parentNode,T=A.rootNode!==document,R=a.length&&(s===r||!1!==s.useFlex)&&!T&&-1!==getComputedStyle(A,null).display.indexOf("flex");return function(){0===arguments.length?v({}):t(arguments,function(t){v(M(t)?{selector:t}:t)}),f=E.length}.apply(n,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)),t(a,function(t,e){N?N!==t.parentNode&&(k=!1):N=t.parentNode;var a=E[0],r=a.hasFilter,o=a.selector,n=!o||r&&t.matchesSelector(o)||o&&t.querySelector(o)?Y:$,s={elm:t,pos:e,posn:n.length};D.push(s),n.push(s)}),x=Y.slice(0),Y.sort(function(e,a){var n=0;for(0!==h&&(h=0);0===n&&f>h;){var s=E[h],d=s.ignoreDashes?c:l;if(t(u,function(t){var e=t.prepare;e&&e(s)}),s.sortFunction)n=s.sortFunction(e,a);else if("rand"==s.order)n=Math.random()<.5?1:-1;else{var p=o,m=C(e,s),v=C(a,s),w=""===m||m===r,S=""===v||v===r;if(m===v)n=0;else if(s.emptyEnd&&(w||S))n=w&&S?0:w?1:-1;else{if(!s.forceStrings){var y=M(m)?m&&m.match(d):o,x=M(v)?v&&v.match(d):o;y&&x&&m.substr(0,m.length-y[0].length)==v.substr(0,v.length-x[0].length)&&(p=!o,m=i(y[0]),v=i(x[0]))}n=m===r||v===r?0:s.natural&&(isNaN(m)||isNaN(v))?b(m,v,g):v>m?-1:m>v?1:0}}t(u,function(t){var e=t.sort;e&&(n=e(s,p,m,v,n))}),0==(n*=s.sortReturnNumber)&&h++}return 0===n&&(n=e.pos>a.pos?1:-1),n}),function(){var t=Y.length===D.length;if(k&&t)R?Y.forEach(function(t,e){t.elm.style.order=e}):N?N.appendChild(w()):console.warn("parentNode has been removed");else{var e=E[0].place,a="start"===e,r="end"===e,o="first"===e,n="last"===e;if("org"===e)Y.forEach(S),Y.forEach(function(t,e){y(x[e],t.elm)});else if(a||r){var s=x[a?0:x.length-1],d=s&&s.elm.parentNode,i=d&&(a&&d.firstChild||d.lastChild);i&&(i!==s.elm&&(s={elm:i}),S(s),r&&d.appendChild(s.ghost),y(s,w()))}else(o||n)&&y(S(x[o?0:x.length-1]),w())}}(),Y.map(function(t){return t.elm})},{plugin:a,defaults:m})}()),function(t,e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery","tinysort","moment"],e):e(t.jQuery,t.tinysort,t.moment||void 0)}(this,function(t,e,a){var r,o,n,s=t(document);function d(e){var s=void 0!==a;r=e.sign?e.sign:"arrow","default"==e.customSort&&(e.customSort=c),o=e.customSort||o||c,n=e.emptyEnd,t("table.sortable").each(function(){var r=t(this),o=!0===e.applyLast;r.find("span.sign").remove(),r.find("> thead [colspan]").each(function(){for(var e=parseFloat(t(this).attr("colspan")),a=1;a<e;a++)t(this).after('<th class="colspan-compensate">')}),r.find("> thead [rowspan]").each(function(){for(var e=t(this),a=parseFloat(e.attr("rowspan")),r=1;r<a;r++){var o=e.parent("tr"),n=o.next("tr"),s=o.children().index(e);n.children().eq(s).before('<th class="rowspan-compensate">')}}),r.find("> thead tr").each(function(e){t(this).find("th").each(function(a){var r=t(this);r.addClass("nosort").removeClass("up down"),r.attr("data-sortcolumn",a),r.attr("data-sortkey",a+"-"+e)})}),r.find("> thead .rowspan-compensate, .colspan-compensate").remove(),r.find("th").each(function(){var e=t(this);if(void 0!==e.attr("data-dateformat")&&s){var o=parseFloat(e.attr("data-sortcolumn"));r.find("td:nth-child("+(o+1)+")").each(function(){var r=t(this);r.attr("data-value",a(r.text(),e.attr("data-dateformat")).format("YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/ss"))})}else if(void 0!==e.attr("data-valueprovider")){o=parseFloat(e.attr("data-sortcolumn"));r.find("td:nth-child("+(o+1)+")").each(function(){var a=t(this);a.attr("data-value",new RegExp(e.attr("data-valueprovider")).exec(a.text())[0])})}}),r.find("td").each(function(){var e=t(this);void 0!==e.attr("data-dateformat")&&s?e.attr("data-value",a(e.text(),e.attr("data-dateformat")).format("YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/ss")):void 0!==e.attr("data-valueprovider")?e.attr("data-value",new RegExp(e.attr("data-valueprovider")).exec(e.text())[0]):void 0===e.attr("data-value")&&e.attr("data-value",e.text())});var n=l(r),d=n.bsSort;r.find('> thead th[data-defaultsort!="disabled"]').each(function(e){var a=t(this),r=a.closest("table.sortable");a.data("sortTable",r);var s=a.attr("data-sortkey"),i=o?n.lastSort:-1;d[s]=o?d[s]:a.attr("data-defaultsort"),void 0!==d[s]&&o===(s===i)&&(d[s]="asc"===d[s]?"desc":"asc",u(a,r))})})}function i(e){var a=t(e),r=a.data("sortTable")||a.closest("table.sortable");u(a,r)}function l(e){var a=e.data("bootstrap-sortable-context");return void 0===a&&(a={bsSort:[],lastSort:void 0},e.find('> thead th[data-defaultsort!="disabled"]').each(function(e){var r=t(this),o=r.attr("data-sortkey");a.bsSort[o]=r.attr("data-defaultsort"),void 0!==a.bsSort[o]&&(a.lastSort=o)}),e.data("bootstrap-sortable-context",a)),a}function c(t,a){e(t,a)}function u(e,a){a.trigger("before-sort");var s=parseFloat(e.attr("data-sortcolumn")),d=l(a),i=d.bsSort;if(e.attr("colspan")){var c=parseFloat(e.data("mainsort"))||0,f=parseFloat(e.data("sortkey").split("-").pop());if(a.find("> thead tr").length-1>f)return void u(a.find('[data-sortkey="'+(s+c)+"-"+(f+1)+'"]'),a);s+=c}var h=e.attr("data-defaultsign")||r;if(a.find("> thead th").each(function(){t(this).removeClass("up").removeClass("down").addClass("nosort")}),t.browser.mozilla){var p=a.find("> thead div.mozilla");void 0!==p&&(p.find(".sign").remove(),p.parent().html(p.html())),e.wrapInner('<div class="mozilla"></div>'),e.children().eq(0).append('<span class="sign '+h+'"></span>')}else a.find("> thead span.sign").remove(),e.append('<span class="sign '+h+'"></span>');var m=e.attr("data-sortkey"),v="desc"!==e.attr("data-firstsort")?"desc":"asc",b=i[m]||v;d.lastSort!==m&&void 0!==i[m]||(b="asc"===b?"desc":"asc"),i[m]=b,d.lastSort=m,"desc"===i[m]?(e.find("span.sign").addClass("up"),e.addClass("up").removeClass("down nosort")):e.addClass("down").removeClass("up nosort");var g=a.children("tbody").children("tr"),w=[];t(g.filter('[data-disablesort="true"]').get().reverse()).each(function(e,a){var r=t(a);w.push({index:g.index(r),row:r}),r.remove()});var S=g.not('[data-disablesort="true"]');if(0!=S.length){var y="asc"===i[m]&&n;o(S,{emptyEnd:y,selector:"td:nth-child("+(s+1)+")",order:i[m],data:"value"})}t(w.reverse()).each(function(t,e){0===e.index?a.children("tbody").prepend(e.row):a.children("tbody").children("tr").eq(e.index-1).after(e.row)}),a.find("> tbody > tr > td.sorted,> thead th.sorted").removeClass("sorted"),S.find("td:eq("+s+")").addClass("sorted"),e.addClass("sorted"),a.trigger("sorted")}if(t.bootstrapSortable=function(t){null==t?d({}):t.constructor===Boolean?d({applyLast:t}):void 0!==t.sortingHeader?i(t.sortingHeader):d(t)},s.on("click",'table.sortable>thead th[data-defaultsort!="disabled"]',function(t){i(this)}),!t.browser){t.browser={chrome:!1,mozilla:!1,opera:!1,msie:!1,safari:!1};var f=navigator.userAgent;t.each(t.browser,function(e){t.browser[e]=!!new RegExp(e,"i").test(f),t.browser.mozilla&&"mozilla"===e&&(t.browser.mozilla=!!new RegExp("firefox","i").test(f)),t.browser.chrome&&"safari"===e&&(t.browser.safari=!1)})}t(t.bootstrapSortable)}),function(){var t=$("table");t.append(newTableRow()),t.append(newTableRow()),$("button.add-row").on("click",function(){var e=$(this);t.append(newTableRow()),e.data("sort")?$.bootstrapSortable(!0):$.bootstrapSortable(!1)}),$("button.change-sort").on("click",function(){$(this).data("custom")?$.bootstrapSortable(!0,void 0,customSort):$.bootstrapSortable(!0,void 0,"default")}),t.on("sorted",function(){alert("Table was sorted.")}),$("#event").on("change",function(){$(this).is(":checked")?t.on("sorted",function(){alert("Table was sorted.")}):t.off("sorted")}),$("input[name=sign]:radio").change(function(){$.bootstrapSortable(!0,$(this).val())})}();
```

```css
table.sortable span.sign { display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 5px; font-size: 12px; margin-top: -10px; color: #bfbfc1; } table.sortable th:after { display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 5px; font-size: 12px; margin-top: -10px; color: #bfbfc1; } table.sortable th.arrow:after { content: ''; } table.sortable span.arrow, span.reversed, th.arrow.down:after, th.reversedarrow.down:after, th.arrow.up:after, th.reversedarrow.up:after { border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; font-size: 0; border-color: #ccc transparent transparent transparent; line-height: 0; height: 0; width: 0; margin-top: -2px; } table.sortable span.arrow.up, th.arrow.up:after { border-color: transparent transparent #ccc transparent; margin-top: -7px; } table.sortable span.reversed, th.reversedarrow.down:after { border-color: transparent transparent #ccc transparent; margin-top: -7px; } table.sortable span.reversed.up, th.reversedarrow.up:after { border-color: #ccc transparent transparent transparent; margin-top: -2px; } table.sortable span.az:before, th.az.down:after { content: "a .. z"; } table.sortable span.az.up:before, th.az.up:after { content: "z .. a"; } table.sortable th.az.nosort:after, th.AZ.nosort:after, th._19.nosort:after, th.month.nosort:after { content: ".."; } table.sortable span.AZ:before, th.AZ.down:after { content: "A .. Z"; } table.sortable span.AZ.up:before, th.AZ.up:after { content: "Z .. A"; } table.sortable span._19:before, th._19.down:after { content: "1 .. 9"; } table.sortable span._19.up:before, th._19.up:after { content: "9 .. 1"; } table.sortable span.month:before, th.month.down:after { content: "jan .. dec"; } table.sortable span.month.up:before, th.month.up:after { content: "dec .. jan"; } table.sortable thead th:not([data-defaultsort=disabled]) { cursor: pointer; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; } table.sortable thead th:hover:not([data-defaultsort=disabled]) { background: #efefef; } table.sortable thead th div.mozilla { position: relative; }
```

```html
<link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css rel=stylesheet><div class=container><div class=hero-unit><h1>Bootstrap Sortable</h1></div><table class="sortable table table-bordered table-striped"><thead><tr><th style=width:20%;vertical-align:middle data-defaultsign=nospan class=az data-defaultsort=asc rowspan=2><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>Name<th style=text-align:center colspan=4 data-mainsort=3>Results<th data-defaultsort=disabled><tr><th style=width:20% colspan=2 data-mainsort=1 data-firstsort=desc>Round 1<th style=width:20%>Round 2<th style=width:20%>Total<th style=width:20% data-defaultsign=month>Date<tbody></table><table class="sortable table table-bordered table-striped"><thead><tr><th style=width:20%;vertical-align:middle data-defaultsign=nospan class=az data-defaultsort=asc rowspan=2><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>Name<th style=text-align:center colspan=4 data-mainsort=3>Results<th data-defaultsort=disabled><tr><th style=width:20% colspan=2 data-mainsort=1 data-firstsort=desc>Round 1<th style=width:20%>Round 2<th style=width:20%>Total<th style=width:20% data-defaultsign=month>Date<tbody></table><div class=well><button class="btn btn-primary add-row"type=button data-sort=true>Add Row (use last sort)</button> <button class="btn btn-primary add-row"type=button>Add Row (use default sort)</button></div><div class=well><button class="btn btn-primary change-sort"type=button data-custom=true>Set custom sorting</button> <button class="btn btn-primary change-sort"type=button>Reset built-in sorting</button></div><div class=well><span class=groupbox>Options</span><div class=well style=margin-top:10px><span class=groupbox>Event</span><div class=checkbox><label><input id=event type=checkbox checked>Hook on 'sorted' event</label></div></div><div class=well><span class=groupbox>Sorting sign</span><div class=radio><label><input id=default type=radio name=sign checked>Default (points towards larger value)</label></div><div class=radio><label><input id=reversed type=radio name=sign value=reversed>Reversed (points towards smaller value)</label></div><div class=radio><label><input id=az type=radio name=sign value=az>a..z</label></div><div class=radio><label><input id=AZ type=radio name=sign value=AZ>A..Z</label></div><div class=radio><label><input id=19 type=radio name=sign value=_19>1..9</label></div><div class=radio><label><input id=month type=radio name=sign value=month>jan..dec</label></div></div></div></div><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js></script><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js></script>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I've seen prevent default, but I wasn't familiar with stop propagation.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Comment: This answer made my day. Thanks!. One point though, if someone wants to replicate the above, they should just copy the code from the code snippet instead of going to the link `Bootstrap Docs` since the link mentions incorrect bootstrap libraries.

Comment: I really like the bootstrap-sortable from drvic10k. It's simple and small.

Comment: What the point to put a snippet with minified/obfuscated code? Ok it is on a single line, great, but it is completely unreadable, and it doesn't help.

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier It's pretty simple, there are/where size limits to what you can post so without minifying these examples they couldn't be added (the vast majority of which is basic tabular data). Copy & paste into an editor, format...minimal effort.

Comment: @MartinZvarík I love that you left this comment! Thanks a lot :D (sarcasm) ... FYI: there are tools like reading also