# Bootstrap-Table Filter Greater/Smaller than

Tags: html, filter, bootstrap-table

for my web project I'm going to use the "Bootstrap-Table" extension. I've some integer values in my table, for example the age of a person and I want to filter the age with greater/smaller than a number. 
In the current BS table issues there is only an example for filtering an integer value equal to a number.

Is there a possibility for this filter option?

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap - How to sort table columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888566/bootstrap-how-to-sort-table-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a W3Schools example for generalized filtering

`www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp`

Here is a Pen for bootstrap with both search and dropdown filtering

`codepen.io/AurelieT/pen/JGxMgo`

Check out the JS Settings to find the code for filtering

Here is a official Bootstrap extension that does what you want.:

`github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/filter-control`

Here is a fiddle:

`jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52ak9/1/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems like my question wasn't clear enough. I know that it is possible JS and other options, but I use the build-in function of "filterBy" of the bootstrap-table. I was thinking that there must be already a greater oder smaller possibility? Or do I have really to build a work around with JS etc?

Comment: Ah, so your looking for sorting, not filtering. Your in luck, stack overflow has that question asked and answered! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888566/bootstrap-how-to-sort-table-columns

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Bootstrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) plugin (sources [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)), you need to use its [Filter Control Extension](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/filter-control/) (sources [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/develop/src/extensions/filter-control))

But, going through the [documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/filter-control/) and [sample page](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/filter-control.html), it seems that filtering by an integer column comparing "less than", "greater than", etc is not supported out of the box.

It also seems that you cannot extend/override the filtering logic without editing the source code.