# Bootstrap Responsive and Sortable Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to implement a "pure", Bootstrap-based responsive and sortable table  (without any plugins and/or only using jQuery)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make responsive table with bootstrap But there is no inbuilt Sorting feature in bootstrap. I use JQuery Plugins or other libraries like [dataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate from [Sort table rows In Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888566/sort-table-rows-in-bootstrap).